# c++ function template specialization with a STL container

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I'm learning STL and templates. Here's my problem. I wrote this function calculating sum of elements "between" two iterators:

```
template <typename Iter> double PartialSum(Iter itBegin, Iter itEnd){
    if (itBegin == itEnd) return 0.;
    double dSum = 0;
    while(itBegin != itEnd){
        dSum += (*itBegin);
        ++itBegin;
    }
    return dSum;
}
```

And this works fine (I know I can use `std::accumulate` but this is for learning purposes). Now, I would like to have the same functionality for `std:map` but iterators there work differently than in the case of `std::vector` and `std::list`. Therefore, I'd like to write overloaded/specialized `PartialSum`. What I tried and failed is this (minimal example):

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> double PartialSum(std::map<T1,T2>::iterator itBegin{
    return 0.;
}
```

This is the error log:

```
Main.cpp(42): error: nontype "std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator [with _Key=T1, _Tp=T2, _Compare=std::less<T1>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const T1, T2>>]" is not a type name template <typename T1, typename T2> double PartialSum(std::map<T1,T2>::iterator itBegin){ Main.cpp(83): error: no instance of overloaded function "PartialSum" matches the argument list argument types are: (std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::string, int>>) std::cout<<"Map partial sum: "<<PartialSum(myMap.begin())<<std::endl;
```

Since it's so simple I probably don't undersatnd something very fundamental. Would be happy to hear your opinion :-)

Comment: Did you accidentally delete half of the line? You haven't finished writing the parameters of the specialization.

Comment: On another note, you cannot partially specialize a function. (That is an overload, not a specialization) You should use a single template function which calls a static function in a template class. This will allow you to partially specialize the class.

Comment: What do you mean with *failed*? A compilation error? Some unexpected runtime behaviour?

Comment: Does a partial some of `pair`s make sense? I don't think so. With such an algorithm, the user has to make sure the iterators yield a working type (e.g., through `boost::adaptors::map_values`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to formulate in another way.

Consider you have function

```
template<typename T>
T f(){
    return T();
}
```

It's impossible here to automatically get T, so you need call it as `f<T>()`. Same goes with

```
template <typename T>
int f(typename type<T>::inner){
     //
}
```

For example, if you have

```
struct type{
    typedef int inner;
}
```

It's easily to see here, that if you call `f(0)` it's impossible to get T.
You may say that's possible to get it in that particular case with `map`, but how will you define it?

You should read c++ standard to read which type should be deducable.

---

In your case you may call in following way

```
PartialSum<std::string, int>(m.begin());
```

---

BTW, It seems, that map is just uncommon case, you may try to do something more general, that will work with any iterator type. You may see `std::accumulate` sources to get some ideas.

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Tp, typename _BinaryOperation>
inline _Tp
accumulate(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Tp __init,
       _BinaryOperation __binary_op)
{
  // concept requirements
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>)
  __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);

  for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
__init = __binary_op(__init, *__first);
  return __init;
}
```

Comment: @ RiaD: could you please reformulate somehow? I'm really trying to understand this thing and I see that there's something in your answer but I don't fully get it.

Comment: @SimonRighley try to checkout

Comment: @ RiaD : Right to the point. Great, it works and I understand why now. Thanks a million! :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the problem that T1 and T2 are not deducible, there is another problem that you're missing the `typename` keyword on a dependent name

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void MyFunction(typename std::map<T1, T2>::iterator it /*, ...*/)
//              ^^^^^^^^^
```

You see, a dependent name is a name dependent on the template arguments. Indeed, there could theoretically be such types T1 and T2 for which the name map::iterator is not a type but is, say, a static data member. The compiler will always assume a data member unless you explicitly specify that it is a type.

You should simply do something like this

```
template<class ValueType, class IteratorType, class Func>
ValueType partialSum(IteratorType first, IteratorType last, ValueType startingValue = ValueType(), Func func = std::plus<ValueType>())
```

And this will cover all cases. To sum a map you will need to provide func that adds two pairs.

Comment: Exactly RiaD, one error disappeared when I added that, but compiler error "no instance of overloaded function "PartialSum" matches the argument list" is still there.

Answer (score -2):

When you dereference a `std::map<T1, T2>::iterator`, you get a `std::pair<const T1, T2>`, where the `.first` element is the key, and the `.second` element is the value.

General structure like this: (code untested, even uncompiled)

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> double PartialSum(std::map<T1,T2>::iterator itBegin, std::map<T1,T2>::iterator itEnd)
{
double dSum = 0;
while(itBegin != itEnd){
    dSum += (itBegin->second);
    ++itBegin;
}
return dSum;
}
```

Comment: OP is not even trying to dereference the iterators yet.

Comment: Yes, exactly. My original code was like the one posted by Marshall Clow and didn't work. I then reduced it to minimum to narrow down the origin of the problem.